# updating the progressbar to include some custom text on the same line as the progressbar

Tags: python

I would like to include some text on the same line as the below progressbar

[progress](https://github.com/niltonvolpato/python-progressbar)

```
string = ["some","text"]
for text in string:
pbar.update(text, i)
```

Would return:

```
>>> text 100%############|
```

Instead of on separate lines:

```
>>> text  
>>> 100%##################|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use widgets

```
from progressbar import ProgressBar, Bar, Percentage
pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=["Hellow Progess: percent:", Percentage(), ",  bar: ", Bar()])
for i in pbar(range(100)):
      time.sleep(0.01)
```